Unable to Override PWADevServer in @magento/pwa-buildpack
I can't overwrite the PWADevServer file located in @magento/pwa-buildpack/lib/WebpackTools/PWADevServer.js.
I added @magento/pwa-buildpack/lib to my .env file under the FOOMAN_OVERRIDEPACKAGES variable like this:
FOOMAN_OVERRIDEPACKAGES='..., ..., @magento/pwa-buildpack/lib'

I also created the necessary folder structure:
.../overrides/pwa-buildpack/WebpackTools/PWADevServer.js

In the overrides folder, I have the following structures for other packages:
.../overrides/venia-ui/... .../overrides/peregrine/...

However, when I add the file
.../overrides/pwa-buildpack/WebpackTools/PWADevServer.js

the override does not work.
How can I start using a custom PWADevServer.js with the override mechanism provided by fooman/venia-ui-override-resolver ?
https://github.com/fooman/venia-ui-override-resolver

